# Add date time stamp for record created and to capture the record changes using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to create a table with has two sets of date time stamps one for when it is created that should show 9999-12-31 and the other date time stamp should reflect the time when any record was changed. How do I write query for this ?

Comment: If the records are not going to be created for 7,811 years, how would they appear in your database?

Comment: Why do you want the rows to be created 8,000 years in the future? You need to look at triggers for this. Or even better is to include updating the DateModified column in your update procedure.

Comment: I think the idea is to set the date to max collating date. @gordon linoff

Comment: Why bother storing it in the database if the value is going to be the same on every row? That sounds like something got missed in understanding the requirements.

Comment: You _think_? Is there anyone who **knows** what's needed? Please clarify your question. Maybe you need to populate some new table based on existing partial data and if no corresponding data found for particular record then you still have to insert a row and set `1999-12-31` instead of real value. Like initializing `history` table which was missing and all one has is `lastmod` date in some rows.

Answer (score 2):

For the first (9999-12-31), you can use a Default value in the table.

For the second ("the time when any record was changed"), you would need to use a trigger.